# ArrayStack Remove method?

Tags: arrays, scala, stack

Is there a method that does the same as Java's `remove` in the `ArrayStack` class?
Or is it possible to write one in Scala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could fit your needs:

```
scala> import collection.mutable.Stack
import collection.mutable.Stack

scala> val s = new Stack[Int]
s: scala.collection.mutable.Stack[Int] = Stack()

scala> s push 1
res0: s.type = Stack(1)

scala> s push 2
res1: s.type = Stack(2, 1)

scala> s push 3
res2: s.type = Stack(3, 2, 1)

scala> s pop
res3: Int = 3

scala> s pop
res4: Int = 2

scala> s pop
res5: Int = 1
```

Or there is also immutable version of the Stack class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filterNot(_ == o)` to create another stack with any instances of `o` missing (at least in 2.9), and you can `stack.slice(0,n) ++ stack.slice(n+1,stack.length)` to create a new stack with in indexed element missing.

But, no, there isn't an exact analog, probably because removing an item at a random position in an array is a low-performance thing to do.

---

Edit: `slice` seems buggy to me, actually, in 2.9.0.RC2 (I have filed a bug report with code to fix it, so this will be fixed for 2.9.0.final, presumably).  And in 2.8.1, you have to create a new `ArrayStack` by hand.  So I guess the answer for now is a pretty emphatic "no".

---

Edit: `slice` has been fixed, so as of 2.9.0.RC4 and later, the slice approach should work.

Comment: ok thanks, even when its a low performance thing to do, it should be implemented in my opinion:P

Comment: @TheBreadCat - It would be nice to have a @slow annotation or somesuch which would warn you when you accidentally use something that has very poor performance compared to what it could have if you were using a different type of collection.  Otherwise, I can see it going both ways--if it's slow, maybe you should still make it _possible_ but not _convenient_.

Comment: the reasson i have to use stacks is becuase im making a game, and i dont want have a limit to how many Entitys there should be able to be. so the easiest way is to use: Entitys.push(new Entity), but when i have to remove one, that the 'problem'.

Comment: `ArrayStack` is only one of the many collections which grow dynamically! I'd recommend to read this to have a better grasp of Scala collections: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Pellet - This should be a comment to the original poster, not to me.  You should @TheBreadCat your comment.

Comment: @Rex Kerr You're right, of course, sorry. I've only just discovered the @ annotations in comments have semantic meaning.

Answer (score 1):

All Scala's collection types support adding/removing elements at either the start or the end (with varying performance trade-offs), and are only limited in size by certain properties of the JVM - such as the maximum size of pointers.

So if this is the only reason that you're using a `Stack`, then you've chosen the wrong collection type.  Given the requirement to be able to remove elements from the middle of the collection, something like a `Vector` would be a **much** better fit.

Comment: is there a function for that or is it just faster?